NetSuite sandbox RESTlet API not fetching order data
I have set up a RESTlet API to fetch order data from "Saved Transaction Search" in NetSuite. In production, it works perfectly. Now I need more functions to be done based on the order data from NetSuite. Without affecting the production, I start to design new functions in the sandbox. The API that works perfectly in production only returns [] in the sandbox.
I have tried redoing the integration, and access taken, and checked all the IDs, but cannot figure out the problems.
Here is the code for print order data:
import time
import uuid
import urllib.parse
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64
import requests

def generate_oauth_signature(method, url, consumer_key, consumer_secret, token_id, token_secret, realm=""):
    params = {
        'oauth_consumer_key': consumer_key,
        'oauth_nonce': uuid.uuid4().hex,
        'oauth_signature_method': 'HMAC-SHA256',
        'oauth_timestamp': str(int(time.time())),
        'oauth_token': token_id,
        'oauth_version': '1.0',
    }

    url_parts = urllib.parse.urlparse(url)
    query_params = urllib.parse.parse_qs(url_parts.query)
    for key, value in query_params.items():
        params[key] = value[0]

    sorted_params = sorted(params.items())


    base_string = method.upper() + '&' + urllib.parse.quote_plus(url_parts.scheme + '://' + url_parts.netloc + url_parts.path) + '&' + urllib.parse.quote_plus('&'.join([urllib.parse.quote_plus(k) + '=' + urllib.parse.quote_plus(v) for k, v in sorted_params]))

    signing_key = urllib.parse.quote_plus(consumer_secret) + '&' + urllib.parse.quote_plus(token_secret)

    signature = hmac.new(signing_key.encode(), base_string.encode(), hashlib.sha256).digest()
    oauth_signature = base64.b64encode(signature).decode()

    auth_header = 'OAuth realm="' + realm + '", '
    auth_header += 'oauth_consumer_key="' + urllib.parse.quote_plus(consumer_key) + '", '
    auth_header += 'oauth_token="' + urllib.parse.quote_plus(token_id) + '", '
    auth_header += 'oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256", '
    auth_header += 'oauth_timestamp="' + params['oauth_timestamp'] + '", '
    auth_header += 'oauth_nonce="' + params['oauth_nonce'] + '", '
    auth_header += 'oauth_version="1.0", '
    auth_header += 'oauth_signature="' + urllib.parse.quote_plus(oauth_signature) + '"'

    return auth_header

def fetch_netsuite_orders():
    #This is for production
    '''  
    netsuite_url = "https://11111111.restlets.api.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=111&deploy=1"
    consumer_key = "11111111"
    consumer_secret = "11111111"
    token_id = "11111111"
    token_secret = "111111111"
    realm = "11111111"
    '''

    #This is for sandbox
    netsuite_url = "https://11111111-sb1.restlets.api.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=111&deploy=1"
    consumer_key = "11111111"
    consumer_secret = "11111111"
    token_id = "11111111"
    token_secret = "11111111"
    realm = "11111111_SB1"
    
    auth_header = generate_oauth_signature("GET", netsuite_url, consumer_key, consumer_secret, token_id, token_secret, realm)
    #print(auth_header)

    headers = {
        'Authorization': auth_header,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }

    response = requests.get(netsuite_url, headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        #print("Success")
        #print(response.json())
        return response.json()
    else:
        print(f"Failed to fetch orders, status code: {response.status_code}")
        print(response.text)
        return []
        

def fetch_orders():
    orders_data = fetch_netsuite_orders()
    return orders_data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    orders_data = fetch_orders()
    print(orders_data)


Here is the code for API:
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType Restlet
 */

define(['N/search'], function(search) {

    function doGet(requestParams) {
        var searchId = 'customsearch696000';
        var searchResults = [];

        var mySearch = search.load({
            id: searchId
        });

        var resultSet = mySearch.run();
        var searchIndex = 0;
        var result;

        do {
            result = resultSet.getRange({
                start: searchIndex,
                end: searchIndex + 1000
            });

            if (result && result.length > 0) {
                searchResults = searchResults.concat(result);
                searchIndex += result.length;
            }
        } while (result && result.length == 1000);

        return searchResults;
    }

    return {
        'get': doGet
    };
});



You're specifying a searchId to get the results from.  Is this ID the same in sandbox and production?

Yes. The IDs are the same.

At least part of your problem is due to incorrect signature generation...
Generate your signature with only the baseUrl: https://11111111-sb1.restlets.api.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl, and use the query parameters ONLY when you generate your "params" (in alphabetical order), so just split those out before you call your 'generate_oauth_signature' function:
#This is for sandbox
netsuite_url = "https://11111111-sb1.restlets.api.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=111&deploy=1"
baseUrl = "https://11111111-sb1.restlets.api.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl"
scriptId = "111"
deployId = "1"
.
.
.
auth_header = generate_oauth_signature("GET", baseUrl, scriptId, deployId, consumer_key, consumer_secret, token_id, token_secret, realm)



def generate_oauth_signature(method, baseUrl, scriptId, deployId, consumer_key, consumer_secret, 
token_id, token_secret, realm=""):
params = {
    'deploy': deployId,
    'oauth_consumer_key': consumer_key,
    'oauth_nonce': uuid.uuid4().hex,
    'oauth_signature_method': 'HMAC-SHA256',
    'oauth_timestamp': str(int(time.time())),
    'oauth_token': token_id,
    'oauth_version': '1.0',
    'script': scriptId
}

But still use the full url for the request once signature is generated. Also,
for some Netsuite calls, a header of Prefer 'transient' is required:
 headers = {
    'Authorization': auth_header,
    'Prefer', "transient" ,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

response = requests.get(netsuite_url, headers=headers)

Also, specifying the  Content-Type in the headers  directly can  sometimes kick back an error with Netsuite. I communicate with c# from an api mostly,  so that may differ here with your code. Since i instead  specify the content-type of application/json only the payload i send. Just an fyi. Good luck!
